# Scala Lesson "Currying"

Tags: scala, currying

I'm newbie with Scala, I'm having issue with currying and can't understand of how below code answer is 144. Hope you guys can help me here.

Thanks

```
def product (f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int) : Int =
   if(a>b) 1
   else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)

product(x => x * x)(3, 4) //answer = 144
```

Comment: How do you get the idea that currying is involved here? (it's not)

Comment: @subsub it is common confusion in scala community to see curring when multiple parameter lists are involved. The reason, probably, is because usually the later unlocks the former.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I guess it is. Reason I asked was it's called "Lesson" so it appears someone is teaching that that's currying. I'd rather ask that person to stop than have more people think "multiple parameter lists" = currying.

Comment: subsub & om-nom-nom, Thank you guys for checking and commenting in this question. Anyway I'm taking a lesson in cousera - scala by Martin Odersky, Lecture 2.3 Currying. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I did not post the whole code and post only the part that I did not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is nothing related with `currying`. You could rewrite your `product` method like this:

```
def product(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int) : Int =
   if(a>b) 1
   else f(a) * product(f, a + 1, b)

val f = (x: Int) => x*x

product(f, 3, 4) // still 144
```

You could replace `product(f, a, b)` with `f(a) * product(f, a+1, b)` (in case a <= b) or with `1`, you could also replace `f(a)` with `a*a`:

```
product(f, 3, 4) ==
9 * product(f, 4, 4) ==
9 * ( 16 * product(f, 5, 4) ) ==
9 * ( 16 * 1 ) ==
144
```

Answer (score 0):

First argument of this method is a function that maps integer to integer, ie. in given example, it squares the number passed to it.

Function 'product' then uses that function (passed as first parameter), and applies it to first argument ('a') and multiplies that result to recursive call to 'product' with same 'f', but with first argument incremented.
As you can notice, parameter named 'b' doesn't play any computational role, other than limit to number of executions of function 'product'.

So, to resolve that call of 'product', we begin with 'a = 3, b = 4'.
First, as 'a' is less than or equal to 'b', we go to else branch where we square (apply 'f') first parameter 'a' (which gives 9), and then multiply that with 'product(f)(4, 4)'.
We also go to else branch here and there we square 4 (as value of 'a' in this execution of 'product') to get 16 and multiply it with 'product(f)(5, 4)'.
Here, 'a' is greater than 'b', so we end 'product' with value 1.

As we propagate that back, we get 1 * 16 * 9 which, in turn equals 144.